# Puppeteer await page.$$eval select

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

Alguien me puede ayudar:

tengo el siguiente selector:

```
 <select id="selectEducacionUniversitaria" name="idTitulacion">
    <option value ="1" > Primera seleccion </option>
    <option value ="2" > Segunda seleccion </option>
    <option value ="3" > tercera seleccion </option>
    <option value ="4" > Cuarta seleccion </option>
  </select>
```

Estoy trabajando con Puppeteer y me estoy guiando de la siguiente documentación:

https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.2.1&show=api-pageevalselector-pagefunction-args-1

Necesito obtener todos los value en un array pero con la documentación he logrado obtener es el text de cada opción de la siguiente manera:

```
 const title = await page.$$eval('#selectEducacionUniversitaria', options => options.map(option => option.textContent));
```

lo cual me regresa lo siguiente:

```
title = ["Primera selección", "Segunda selección", "Tercera selección", "Cuarta selección"]
```

y necesito lo siguiente:
title = [1,2,3,4]

Nota: He intentado obtenerlo con el option.value y me retonar [''].

Como podría obtenerlo?

Gracias ante mano!

Answer (score 0):

Aunque en la documentación no salga deberias acostumbrarte a poner un `{ }` en el contenido de la función `pageFunction`(osea el parametro function que toma `$$()`) y colocarle un `return` quedando de la siguiente forma:

```
const title = await page.$$eval('#selectEducacionUniversitaria > option', options =>{ return options.map(option => option.value)});
```

[Aquí](https://github.com/checkly/puppeteer-examples/blob/25a02618f6e5a2b1f2eda9e4a3b97b6091fc6491/1.%20basics/forms.js) hay un ejemplo de su uso (ademas de muchos otros ejemplos usando esta libreria)

Comment: Y por qué debería acostumbrarse a poner corchetes a una arrow function?? Solo se deben poner si o si cuando es multilínea, y te obliga a incluir el return. En caso de que vayas a devolver una única llamada a función u objeto puedes obviarlos, así como el `return`.

Comment: Chill. Solo estoy dando una recomendación basandome en código ya escrito usando la libreria Puppeteer

Comment: Chill, solo estoy comentando que no es necesario poner los corchetes en una arrow function. Que se pueden poner? Si, claro que si. Que "Debería" acostumbrarse a hacerlo? No lo creo. No gana absolutamente nada con ello. Los `{}` se usan para delimitar *bloques de código*, indicando a la arrow function que todo lo que hay entre ellos forma parte del cuerpo de la misma. Si no se indican y se hace una única llamada se asume que esa llamada es el cuerpo de la función y nada más.

Comment: En ningun momento dije que tu aclaratoria sobre el uso de {} fuera incorrecta, simplemente como mencione es una "recomendación", de la misma forma como alguien que escribe declaraciones sin finalizar con un ";" le recomiendas que las use para evitar "resultados inesperados", no es una obligación

Comment: @AnkiJedi gracias por responder, pero como comente anteriormente el option.value no me retorna lo que necesito. De igual manera probé con tu solución para corroborar antes de comentar y no retorna el resultado esperado, me arroja => [' ']. De igual manera muchas gracias!

Comment: Cambie el código,  podrías probar con este por favor?